# What is this medieval fantasy TV show?

Tags: story-identification, medieval

I remember seeing a TV show in the 90s (I am not sure when it was first aired). It...:

- Has a medieval setting
- Has a handful of heroes, all young men and women (ie: mid to high teens)  *à la* Power Rangers
- The protagonists use weapons/powers based on the classical elements: Fire, Water, Earth, Air/Wind

Does anyone know what the name of the show?

Comment: It was live action _à la_ Power Rangers as well?

Comment: @Xantec Yes, they were played by real people. I don't recall there being monster like in Power Rangers though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it have been the [Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystic_Knights_of_Tir_Na_Nog)? That was very much like Power Rangers.

Comment: Wow, you nailed it!